# How can I create a fake microphone in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, microphone, privacy

Blackboard and Zoom on Firefox both require microphone permissions even if the microphone is never to be used. You can mute your microphone in those services and on your physical computer but I am still uncomfortable with giving those services the microphone permissions (not just because you can forget to mute your mic). Is it possible to create a dummy microphone that Firefox will detect and I can give permissions to so I can get rid of this paranoia?

Comment: Lemme install Pulse Audio as per your link and get back to you

Comment: When using Pulse Audio (pavucontrol for Ubuntu), instead of sending the audio output to the input as per the linked post, I found that you can set the input device (microphone) to a previously plugged in microphone. So, you can plug in a mic, unplug it, and from then on set the input device to the now unplugged microphone. This works just as well.